# How to get the ID of the record created in the model after saving it from a Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Let's say I submit a form to the back-end and I save a record of the model in the following way:

`views.py`:

```
def viewName(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() #I want to get the id of this after it is saved
        else:
            print (form.errors)
            form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

Right after saving the form, I would like to get the id of the record for the model.

I tried with `form.id` and `form.pk` as I saw in other similar questions without success.

How can I get the `id` or the `pk` of the new entry added to the `Project` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.save()` returns the object, so:

```
obj = form.save()
print(obj.pk)
```